# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils

I am trying to create a library distributed with pip.

```
sudo python setup.py sdist upload -r pypitest
```

when I try to install it with

```
sudo pip install -i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi abce
```

It fails with

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas>=0.17 (from abce) (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for pandas>=0.17 (from abce)

I tried no for a day, but I can't make it work. When I install pandas with `pip install pandas` it installs the 0.18.1 version. What am I doing wrong?

The setup.py is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

try:
    from setuptools import setup
    from setuptools import Extension
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
    from distutils.extension import Extension


cmdclass = { }
ext_modules = [ ]

try:
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
    ext_modules += [
        Extension("abce.trade", [ "abce/trade.pyx" ]),
    ]
    cmdclass.update({ 'build_ext': build_ext })
except ImportError:
    ext_modules += [
        Extension("abce.trade", [ "abce/trade.c" ]),
    ]

setup(name='abce',
      version='0.5.07b',
      author='Davoud Taghawi-Nejad',
      author_email='Davoud@Taghawi-Nejad.de',
      description='Agent-Based Complete Economy modelling platform',
      url='https://github.com/DavoudTaghawiNejad/abce.git',
      package_dir={'abce': 'abce'},
      packages=['abce'],
      long_description=open('README.rst').read(),
      install_requires=['numpy>=1.9',
                        'pandas>=0.17',
                        'networkx>=1.9',
                        'flask>=0.10',
                        'bokeh>=0.11',
                        'matplotlib>=1.3'],
      include_package_data=True,
      ext_modules=ext_modules,
      cmdclass=cmdclass)
```

Answer (score 1):

On day later:

pip was searching the packages on piptest, but actually the ABCE package should come from piptest and the requirments should come from pip:

```
sudo pip install -i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi --extra-index-url https://pypi.python.org/pypi abce
```